# Not throwing index out of bounds in Swift closure

Tags: swift, closures, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm making a parse query in my iOS app. If the query comes up empty, I get an empty object array. But when I index into that array with `objects![0]` it does *not* throw any kind of error, and no messages display in the bottom pane/debug area. I put print statements around the suspicious statement. It prints `foo` but never prints `bar`.

```
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    print("foo")
    let _ = objects![0]
    print("bar")
}
```

I suspected that <s>exceptions</s> runtime errors weren't handled normally if running in a background thread, but that isn't the case either. I ran the following code, and got a `Fatal error: Index out of range` just as you would expect. This means it has something to do with the `objects` variable.

```
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    let x:[PFObject]? = []
    print("foo")
    let _ = x![0]
    print("bar")
}
```

Comment: First of all, note that these are not _exceptions_ (you can't really catch them as e.g. in python's index out of bounds exceptions), but are runtime errors: once you run into them you should consider your app to be in a crashing state (the same holds for a failed forceful unwrapping (`!`)). As for the questions from a curiosity aspect: are you testing in release mode? Possibly the optimizer simply removes the line `let _ = objects![0]`, as you are discarding the result while accessing an immutable object by `subscript` -> compiler possibly treats this read as no side effects (on the object).

Comment: ... and possible there's some subtle difference to the local immutable `x` (as compared to the supplied immutable `objects`).

Comment: Even if `let _ = objects![0]` was optimized away, it doesn't explain why the `print("bar")` never executes.

Comment: Really sure that `objects == []`? Then you could `assert` that to be extra sure. Also, I'd put in some more logging: print the value of `objects` and of the return value of `objects![0]`.

Comment: I'm certain `objects == []` because I check it before-hand. And even it were nil, the unwrapping should still throw an error